# PHP sql query Subtract two dateTime fields to a millisecond (d-m-Y H:i:s.ms)

Tags: php, sql, datetime, mysqli

I have two fields in a sql query for a html table that needs to be subtracted. The datetime format looks like this "19/08/2017 23:32:08.580"
My sql with inner joins looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT tblentries.categories,
    tblracedetails.actual_start_time,
    tblentries.age,
    tblentries.firstname,
    tblentries.surname,
    tblentries.distance,
    tblentries.raceid,
    tblracetime.finishtime,
    tblracetime.raceno,
    tblentries.racedate,
    tblentries.racename,
    TIMEDIFF('tblracetime.finishtime','tblracedetails.actual_start_time') AS racetimes
FROM tblentries
INNER JOIN tblracetime
    ON tblentries.raceid = tblracetime.racesid AND tblentries.raceno = tblracetime.raceno
INNER JOIN tblracedetails
    ON tblracedetails.id = tblentries.racesid AND tblracedetails.distance = tblentries.distance
";
```

The data is stored in a varchar fields called "actual_start_time" and "finishtime". The final subtracted format should be h:m:s:ms and the subtracted value must be called "racetimes" .
The sql query above displayed, works 100% except for an empty 00:00:00 racetimes column.
Any suggestions will be appreciated? Thx

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?  I don't believe that mysql < 5.6 supports miliseconds.

Comment: I use XAMPP -   PHP version: 7.0.9 and MYSQLi

Comment: That doesn't tell me what version of mySQL you're using.  Run `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: I got it working

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing that  sql  part to

> TIMEDIFF(tblracetime.finishtime,tblracedetails.actual_start_time) times

and the actual field to a datetime with millisecond, using

> ALTER TABLE tblracedetails ADD actual_start_time datetime(3)

and changing date format added to fields like so  "yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s.ms" format